# Entity Framework Code First Database Migrations - Multple instances of APP with Single DB Server

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, database-migration

So transitioning from the development/deployment approach of

- Have DB under Source Control and have deployment pipeline for specific versions of the DB
- Have Web App/API under Source Control and have deployment pipelines for these;

and then have dependencies of the Web APP/API on DB Versions - hence to add a new DB change for example we have to do a DB release; before we do an APP release - and the DB change has to not 'break' the old app - and then we can upgrade the App to use the new DB Change

Whilst painful - this works; it also works when you have N Servers for the web app (horizontal scale) with a suitably SINGLE DB Server.

Now working towards EF Core 3.1 Code First using Data Migrations. All working as expected one a single web app with single DB.

But - if this was deployed to N Web Servers, again with a single DB instance; Then.....

- "IF" Web Servers upgraded one at a time then then Data Migration would occur on the start up of the first "new" app - and potentially the old web apps would continue to work (depends on the changes)

The above isn't really my concern; it's

- If you have simultaneous deployment over multiple web app servers and these apps start at the same time; then I imagine the Data Migrations would be attempted all at the same time.... meaning one of them must fail.

So: $64,000 Question - how do people deal with the horiztonal scale out of Web app with Single DB Server with EF Code First Data Migrations?

Is it "just be careful with your changes"?

Answer (score 0):

> how do people deal with the horiztonal scale out of Web app with Single DB Server with EF Code First Data Migrations?

[Applying migrations at runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime) is suitable only for dev and simple production deployments.

The most common pattern here is to generate the database change scripts (perhaps using Migrations, perhaps using a database-oriented tool like [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15)), review the changes for backwards-compatibility and ability to be applied online, and deploy them first.